# Delete all rows from datagridview and database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

Hi guys as the title says i want to delete all rows from a datagridview and in the process deleting them from the database. Heres my code but its only deleting one row and not all. Thank you

```
     private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.dgvProducts.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvProducts.SelectedRows)
            {
                int selectedIndex = dgvProducts.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                int rowID = int.Parse(dgvProducts[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
                 crud.AddRecord("Delete from Supplier_productlist where ProductID = '" + rowID + "' and SupplierID = '"+supplierid.Text+"' ");

            }
        }

        //dgvProducts.Refresh();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the foreach loop, only 0th item was processed.

If you want to specify index, I would suggest for loop instead of foreach.

If you want to use foreach, then you probably should work on "row" itself instead of keep working on 0th item:

```
dgvProducts.SelectedRows[0]
dgvProducts[0, selectedIndex]
```

Comment: i only used that for the specifying the product id for deleting in the database. how can i work on rows instead of 0th item sir?

Comment: Without testing it out, I would suggest to try this first:

replace 
     int selectedIndex = dgvProducts.SelectedRows[0].Index;
by
    int selectedIndex = row.Index;

I think what happens here is that regardless of the foreach loop, in every iteration the code is always extracting the index from the 0th item.

Comment: When running the debugger with breakpoint on the line where int selectedIndex is initiated, we should be able to see different index is being assigned in each iteration. If that's the case, then we are in the right direction, although some more code change may or may not be needed.

Comment: Glad it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're looping over only **SelectedRows**, not all **Rows**.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvProducts.SelectedRows)
```

To loop over the whole datagrid's rows you should use

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvProducts.**Rows**)
```

Hope, this link helps: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still only deleting one row after i changed it. Thanks for the link sir but its russian lol

Comment: Okay. You dont need `int selectedIndex = dgvProducts.SelectedRows[0].Index;` since you can loop over and get rows with `row` variable. Btw, it looks like your `supplierid.Text` fixes the text and only one record from database with `SupplierID = '"+supplierid.Text+"' "` will be affected, may be, you need to remove it at all?

Comment: Here is link in english : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx